# New Theme structure

Tags: magento2

im new user and trying to make a new theme for magento 2 , i read a lot of article and im starting to doing it and i want know the different between this location ? Who`s the css and js master ? and why when i active me new theme , i cant found any data in my site ???

```
TestVender/
└── TestTheme
    ├── etc
    ├── media
    │   └── TestPreview.jpg
    ├── registration.php
    ├── theme.xml
    └── web
        ├── css
        ├── images
        └── js
```

what the different between this folders

```
pup
 └── static
        └── frontend
              └───static
                   └── "my theme" 
                         ├── css
                         ├── images
                         └── js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2 themes and extensions contain all of their own files within themselves in a single directory, e.g app/design/frontend/Magento/blank for a theme, as apposed to Magento 1 where they were spread out over the codebase. This approach has many benefits but one of the side affects is that the static assets are not longer stored in a public facing directory so cannot be served to the browser. To get around this Magento 2 collates all of the static assets for all modules and themes in the system and deploys them to the pub/static directory where they can be served to the browser.

So to answer your question your TestVendor/TestTheme directory is the "master" for your theme, all assets in pub/static are transient they could be removed and redeployed. To deploy static assets you can run "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" from your command line.